# insert value to foreign key

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, asp.net-mvc-3, foreign-keys

problem is with foreign key:

> The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_uzytkownik_Logowanie". The conflict occurred in database
>   "Restauracja", table "dbo.Logowanie", column 'LoginID'.
>   The statement has been terminated.

I check this using breakpoints, and primary key in `Logowanie` table was added when breakpoints (running application) was after

```
baza.SubmitChanges();
```

Primary key of `LoginID` in `logowanie` table is added automatically during `SubmitChanges`.

How to copy value of `LoginID` from `logowanie` table to `LoginID` in `uztkownik` table? I add foreign key value here, but here `LoginID` hasn't value yet.

```
Logowanie newlog = new Logowanie()
{
   Login = model.LoginModel.Użytkownik,
   Haslo = model.LoginModel.Hasło,
   konto = model.LoginModel.Konto
};

uzytkownik user = new uzytkownik()
{
   imie = model.uzytkownikModle.imie,
   nazwisko = model.uzytkownikModle.nazwisko,
   pesel = model.uzytkownikModle.pesel,
   nip = model.uzytkownikModle.nip,
   telefon = model.uzytkownikModle.telefon,
   adres_zamieszkania = model.uzytkownikModle.adres_zamieszkania,
   email = model.uzytkownikModle.email,
   LoginID = newlog.LoginID //<<<----------------
};

baza.Logowanies.InsertOnSubmit(newlog);
baza.uzytkowniks.InsertOnSubmit(user);

baza.SubmitChanges();
```

Comment: Could be same issue as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5560564/the-insert-statement-conflicted-with-the-foreign-key-constraint-fk-tkosikzbozi

Comment: Assuming your have a FK relationship in the database - does your Linq-to-SQL model also have a "link" between those two entities? E.g. does the `user` object have some kind of a `Login` (as a Login object - not just the ID) property?

Comment: My Linq-to-SQL have a "link" `Logowanie.LoginID -> uzytkownik.LoginID`
<img src="http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/507/unledgb.jpg/" width="100" height="100">

Answer (score 0, accepted):

uzytkownik should have a property called Logowanie, which you can set to the new instance you created but didn't Submit yet:

```
user.Logowanie = newlog;
```

Answer (score 0):

Since it's a foreign key relationship, your `Logowanie` class should contain a property for `IQueryable<uzytkownik>` that is used to relate the objects properly in a one-to-many manner. As a result, there is no longer a need to assign the foreign key manually, it can be done through the object heirarchy:

```
Logowanie newlog = new Logowanie()
{
   Login = model.LoginModel.Użytkownik,
   Haslo = model.LoginModel.Hasło,
   konto = model.LoginModel.Konto
};

uzytkownik user = new uzytkownik()
{
   imie = model.uzytkownikModle.imie,
   nazwisko = model.uzytkownikModle.nazwisko,
   pesel = model.uzytkownikModle.pesel,
   nip = model.uzytkownikModle.nip,
   telefon = model.uzytkownikModle.telefon,
   adres_zamieszkania = model.uzytkownikModle.adres_zamieszkania,
   email = model.uzytkownikModle.email,
   // Remove this line entirely   LoginID = newlog.LoginID //<<<----------------
};

// Add the child object (user) to your Logowanie object (newlog)
newlog.uzytkowniks.Add(user)  // This may just be uzytkownik. Pluralization in LINQ is weird

// It is not necessary to queue the user object for insertion
// the newlog object will do that for you
baza.Logowanies.InsertOnSubmit(newlog);
// baza.uzytkowniks.InsertOnSubmit(user);

// SubmitChanges at this point will insert all of the children
// of newlog and assign the IDs properly
baza.SubmitChanges();

// at this point you should be able to get the newlog.LoginID
// and the user.UserID (assuming this is what you called it)
```

When I first ran across this it seemed a little backward to me, but once you break the relationships down into their class representations it really starts to make sense. It's also fantastic that it does all of the relationship assignments for you.

Comment: previously answer work, but your is too interesting. 
You wrote: "Logowanie class should contain a property for IQueryable<uzytkownik>" that mean, add this to my Logowanie model class?
E.g. public class LoginModel :  IQueryable<uzytkownik> { ..... }

newlog.uzytkowniks.Add(user) - I haven't add property... I can generate method stub for 'Add' in 'Restauracja.uzytkownik' , but when I run I had error:
{"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."}

Comment: @user1031034: No, if these classes were created by using a DataContext (.dbml file), then that property should have been auto-generated when you added your tables to it.