# Code first driving me crazy with foreign key exception

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1

These are my model classes:

```
public class Organization
{
        public Organization()
        {
        }

        [DisplayName("Organization Id")]
        public int OrganizationId { get; set; }

        [StringLength(128)]
        [DisplayName("Organization Name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class User 
{
        public User()
        {
            Roles = new List<Role>();
        }

        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)] 
        [Key]
        public Guid UserGuid { get; set; }

        [StringLength(25)]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        [StringLength(25)]
        public string LastName { get; set; }

        public virtual List<Role> Roles { get; set; }

        public int OrganizationId { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("OrganizationId")]
        public virtual Organization Organization { get; set; }
    }
```

This is my code:

```
 Organization organization = new Organization { Name = "Test", };
 context.Organizations.Add(organization);
```

And I get this:

> The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint
>   \"Organization_Users\". The conflict occurred in database
>   \"SampleDB\", table \"dbo.Organizations\", column
>   'OrganizationId'.\r\nThe statement has been terminated.

Isn't this weird? I am just adding an organization. What problem can it possibly have in this?

**P.S:** My user table does have `OrganizationId` that is foreign key and pointing to `Organization` table. So far so good but why is the exception thrown? I am adding a master `Organization` record. How does that violate foreign key constraint?

Comment: If i would have to guess, OrganizationId is the foreign key. Basically meaning that the Organization doesn't exist in what ever table it is referencing.

Comment: Where is the foreign key `Organization_Users`? You don't show it in your code. Is it a field of the `Organization` table?

Comment: @Otiel: It is the name of foreign key relationship that is autogenerated by Sql Server.

Answer (score 1):

I would expect the database id to be generated for the organisation as well:

```
   [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)] 
   [DisplayName("Organization Id")]
   public int OrganizationId { get; set; }
```

Either that, or you need toset it to a valid, unique value yourself before saving

#### Alternative guess:

The name `Organization_Users` suggests that there is (or *was*) a relation from the Organization table to th Users (perhaps via a relation table). Did you show the full code? Code there be remnants of this old relationship in the database? It is not enough to remove such relations just from the C# code (because the datatabase will continue checking the constraints, until the unused fields/relations are dropped from the actual database schema).

Comment: It is already database generated because it is following the convention of className + Id. So Code first automatically make it autogenerated. Anyways, put the explicit attribute of DatabaseGenerated still doesn't solve.

Comment: There is a foreign key relationship that is automatically set because of this code: "[ForeignKey("OrganizationId")]
        public virtual Organization Organization { get; set; }"

Comment: @Otiel: It is not related to the answer.

Comment: Ok. I found the problem. Problem was in Seed method. I was adding a user object there and not assigning organizationId which threw this exception. Sorry for inconvience due to my silly mistake. Wasted 1 hour behind this.

Comment: Hehe. thanks for the update. Perhaps you can answer your question or mark it 'SOLVED' so others won't be wasting time :)

Comment: @Jaggu Please don't mark it SOLVED in the title. Instead either add the correct answer and mark it correct, or if you think it's not worth while then delete the question or flag it for a moderator to delete.

Comment: Mgm, I was getting my crystal ball all ready to produce a duplicate posting [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8021097/insert-value-to-foreign-key/8022550#8022550)

Answer (score 0):

It appears that EF has created the relationship in the wrong direction.

The User class should have an Organization not an OrganizationID.

The Organization class should have a list of users.